# Testing text field input with Spectator

Tags: angular-spectator, spectator

I'm trying to test my directive with `@ngneat/spectator` version 6.1.1

```js
it('should allow all numbers', () => {
    spectator = createDirective('<input appNumbersOnly type="number">')
    const input = spectator.query('input') as HTMLInputElement

    spectator.typeInElement('1234', input)

    expect(input.value).toHaveExactText('1234')
})
```

That always comes back with `input.value` being blank. I'm just getting started with spectator. What's the right way to perform this test?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have a bit different issue - I seem to be able to set the value, however Angular's form.valid property does not seem to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
expect(input.value).toEqual('1234');
```